# how to create search filter and text highlight in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

```js
var app = angular.module('app',['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('searchCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.searchContents = [
  {
   title: 'Hedng one',
   disc_1: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmodtempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodoconsequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit essecillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat nonproident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'
  },
  {
   title: 'Heading tow',
   disc_1: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmodtempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodoconsequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit essecillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat nonproident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.',
   disc_2: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmodtempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodoconsequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit essecillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat nonproident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.',
   disc_3: 'lorem lorem lorem'
  },
  {
   title: 'Heding three',
   disc_1: 'discription..............................................'
  },
  {
   title: 'Heding four',
   disc_1: 'discription..............................................'
  }
 ];
}]);

app.filter('highlight', function () {
  return function (text, search, caseSensitive) {
    if (text && (search || angular.isNumber(search))) {
      text = text.toString();
      search = search.toString();
      if (caseSensitive) {
        return text.split(search).join('<span class="ui-match">' + search + '</span>');
      } else {
        return text.replace(new RegExp(search, 'gi'), '<span class="ui-match">$&</span>');
      }
    } else {
      return text;
    }
  };
});
```

```css
/* Generated by less 2.5.1 */
.ui-match {
  background: #FFC107;
  color: #fff;
}

.side-panel.panel-open {
  transform: translateX(0%);
  display: block;
}
.side-panel li {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.side-panel.side-panel-singlar {
  z-index: 10;
}


.search-results > ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 5%;
}
.search-results > li {
  line-height: 1.3em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/style.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="searchCtrl">
  <div class="side-panel-singla">
    <input type="text" class="input-search" placeholder="Search..." ng-model="searchText" />
    <button class="btn-search">search</button>
    <div  ng-repeat="searchContent in searchContents | filter:searchText">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <h3 ng-bind-html="searchContent.title | highlight:searchText"></h3>
          <p ng-bind-html="searchContent.disc_1 | highlight:searchText"></p>
          <p ng-bind-html="searchContent.disc_2 | highlight:searchText"></p>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It's working fine as it is but I want some improvement in it
my requirement is to show heading only by-default and when user start to search then if searched text fiend in paragraph it should be expand otherwise not expend fiddle demo is as  [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/RichardAD/FUW4A/) but its using kendo I want it in angularjs please help

Answer (score 0):

What follows is a very specific solution for your case. I added class called `hastext` to the style sheet, and then I added an long ng-class directive to a new `<div>` around the paragraph `<p>s`

It's nice because it utilizes your highlight filter, comparing the filtered text to the original, and setting it to true if there's a difference (if it finds any of the inserted `<span>s`). However, if you add more paragraphs, you will also have to add additional lines to that ng-class call.

```js
var app = angular.module('app',['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('searchCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.searchContents = [
  {
   title: 'Hedng one',
   disc_1: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmodtempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodoconsequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit essecillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat nonproident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'
  },
  {
   title: 'Heading tow',
   disc_1: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmodtempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodoconsequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit essecillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat nonproident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.',
   disc_2: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmodtempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodoconsequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit essecillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat nonproident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.',
   disc_3: 'lorem lorem lorem'
  },
  {
   title: 'Heding three',
   disc_1: 'discription..............................................'
  },
  {
   title: 'Heding four',
   disc_1: 'discription..............................................'
  }
 ];
}]);

app.filter('highlight', function () {
  return function (text, search, caseSensitive) {
    if (text && (search || angular.isNumber(search))) {
      text = text.toString();
      search = search.toString();
      if (caseSensitive) {
        return text.split(search).join('<span class="ui-match">' + search + '</span>');
      } else {
        return text.replace(new RegExp(search, 'gi'), '<span class="ui-match">$&</span>');
      }
    } else {
      return text;
    }
  };
});
```

```css
/* Generated by less 2.5.1 */
.ui-match {
  background: #FFC107;
  color: #fff;
}

.side-panel.panel-open {
  transform: translateX(0%);
  display: block;
}
.side-panel li {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.side-panel.side-panel-singlar {
  z-index: 10;
}


.search-results > ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 5%;
}
.search-results > li {
  line-height: 1.3em;
}
.paragraphs {
  height: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.paragraphs.hastext
{
   height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/style.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="searchCtrl">
  <div class="side-panel-singla">
    <input type="text" class="input-search" placeholder="Search..." ng-model="searchText" />
    <button class="btn-search">search</button>
    <div  ng-repeat="searchContent in searchContents" >
      <ul>
        <li>
          <h3 ng-bind-html="searchContent.title | highlight:searchText" ></h3>
          <div class="paragraphs" ng-class="{'hastext' : ((searchContent.title | highlight:searchText) != searchContent.title ||
            (searchContent.disc_1 | highlight:searchText) != searchContent.disc_1 ||
            (searchContent.disc_2 | highlight:searchText) != searchContent.disc_2
          )}">
            <p ng-bind-html="searchContent.disc_1 | highlight:searchText"></p>
            <p ng-bind-html="searchContent.disc_2 | highlight:searchText"></p>
           </div>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```